# Magic number detection for Java

Tags: java, code-analysis

I am looking for a code analysis tool for Java code, which performs a scan for unnamed numerical values, e.g.:

```
double beforeTax = subtotal + 9.99d;
```

Such as [buddy.js](https://github.com/danielstjules/buddy.js) for JavaScript does.

Is there something as that readily available for Java?

Comment: I believe there are multiple such tools. Which one to pick may more be a matter of opinion than needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) is a commonly used tool, build for Java static code analysis. Beside magic numbers it detects a lot of other issues out of the box. You can configure your rule set and it also supports the scanning of other languages.